# How to create unique constraints for active records in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

```
alter table student 
 add constraint student_id_unique unique column(student_id) 
where status='ACTIVE';
```

How to check record is active for unique constraint?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Standard does not provide any way to define the constraint you want. However, it can be done in PostgreSQL (and several other databases) by creating a partial index, with the form:

```
create unique index ix1 on student (student_id) where status = 'ACTIVE';
```

In this case, the insert will succeed as shown below:

```
insert into student (student_id, status) values (1, 'ACTIVE');
insert into student (student_id, status) values (2, 'ACTIVE');
insert into student (student_id, status) values (1, 'INACTIVE'); -- succeeds
insert into student (student_id, status) values (1, 'ACTIVE'); -- fails
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8YvDcStrA8frnWYkf6jDnQ/0).